# Setting up Sphinx Search

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, sphinx

I've been looking for tutorials online to setup sphinx search, and I have got the test database working. However I am having trouble getting my own database to work.

sphinx.conf

```
source src1
{
  type          = mysql

  sql_host      = localhost
  sql_user      = root
  sql_pass      = MyPassword
  sql_db        = MyDatabase
  sql_port      = 3306

  sql_query     = \
  SELECT listing_id, title, description, image_id \
  FROM listings

  sql_attr_uint       = listing_id

  sql_query_info        = SELECT listing_id, title, description, image_id      FROM listings

}
index test1
{
  source            = src1
  path              = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/test1
  docinfo           = extern
  charset_type      = sbcs
}
searchd
{
  listen            = 9312
  log               = /var/log/sphinxsearch/searchd.log
```

However when I try and run:

```
sudo indexer --all --rotate
```

The output in putty is:

```
using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'test1'...
WARNING: attribute 'listing_id' not found - IGNORING
WARNING: Attribute count is 0: switching to none docinfo
WARNING: collect_hits: mem_limit=0 kb too low, increasing to 24576 kb
collected 3 docs, 0.0 MB
sorted 0.0 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 3 docs, 49 bytes
total 0.002 sec, 16740 bytes/sec, 1024.94 docs/sec
total 2 reads, 0.000 sec, 0.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 6 writes, 0.000 sec, 0.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
rotating indices: succesfully sent SIGHUP to searchd (pid=911)
```

However, when I try and run "search df" for example, I get:

```
Sphinx 2.0.4-id64-release (r3135)
Copyright (c) 2001-2012, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2012, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'...
FATAL: 'sql_query_info' value must contain '$id'
```

I am running Sphinx Search on Ubuntu 14.04 using an account called "user" which is part of the sudoers file.

I have lost my mind with this, so would appreciate someones help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `sql_query_info` is invalid. It needs to contain `$id`, as the message says.

However, would highly recommend **not** using `search` tool - its broken. Skip it. (articles recommending its use, are outdated) - sql_query_info is only used by `search`.

Move right on to starting `searchd`, and use `test.php` if dont have an application yet. Using `test.php` to test your index is MUCH better.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. Good to hear, however how do I go about making a PHP script in order to show indexed - not sure how to use PHP in order to do this. I have looked online however the results seem outdated or vague.

Comment: Use test.php :) https://www.google.com/search?q=sphinx+example+api+%22test.php%22